# NSIncrementalStore called with NSSaveChangesRequest.deletedObjects == nil

Tags: ios, core-data, nsincrementalstore

I am in the process of writing an `NSIncrementalStore` that is backed by a REST service. It works nicely for POSTing and GETing objects, but when DELETEing them I encounter the following problem:

1. test calls `[context delete: object];`
2. `context.deletedObjects` contains `object` (as one would expect)
3. test calls `[context save: &error];`
4. iOS calls `NSIncrementalStore`s `executeRequest:withContext:error:` with a `NSSaveChangesRequest`; when the call arrives both `context.deletedObjects == nil` and `saveChangesRequest.deletedObjects == nil`, so my code cannot find out which objects to DELETE from the server.

How can it happen that `deletedObjects` is set to `nil` between the call to the context's `save` and its invocation its `NSIncrementalStore`?

**UPDATE** possible cause: `object.objectID` is still a `temporaryID` following `save`. The `NSIncrementalStore` is currently obtaining object IDs from `newObjectIDForEntity:referenceObject:` and the description from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObjectID/temporaryID) somehow does not seem to apply yet:

> New objects inserted into a managed object context are assigned a
>   temporary ID which is replaced with a permanent one once the object
>   gets saved to a persistent store.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The trouble was that I did not yet store enough information on the server to recreate (permanent) object IDs during fetches.

This solves the problem in `NSIncrementalStore`:

- When `executeRequest:withContext:error:` receives an `NSSaveChangesRequest` it extracts (in my case) reference strings from saved objects with `referenceObjectForObjectID:` and stores these (along with objects' other attributes) on the server.
- When `executeRequest:withContext:error:` receives an `NSFetchRequest` it obtains reference strings (along with objects' other attributes) from the server and recreates objects with `[context objectWithID: [self newObjectIDForEntity: entity referenceObject: referenceString]]`.